# Java components on frame border

Tags: java, swing, awt

Is there a way to place components (like buttons or tabs) on the border of a Frame/JFrame like the Windows explorer does? Since Windows Vista, the explorer has some buttons in the top left corner, and I would like to do something similar with Java.

[image]

Comment: Yes, if you implement your own custom window border as per [here](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-decorated-titlebar-jframe.html), or make a borderless window as per [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaBorderlessWindow.htm) and implement your own close, etc. buttons, you can do it. It will be hard to get it to look just like other windows, especially with windows themes like aero. FYI, Firefox does this too, not sure how though.

Comment: I want it to look like the window in the screenshot, I kinda like the border. Reproducing it would be a nonsense I guess, maybe I'll switch to C++ at some point :D

Comment: That will probably be quite hard then.

Comment: C++? No. Writing something like that in C++  would be way easier than java, since I wouldn't have to worry about platform independence. I hate that java doesn't support something like that out-of-the-box, design gets more important every day.

Comment: @Distjubo I'm pretty sure he was referring to replicating the UI design in Java

Comment: Oh, that kinda makes sense xD Anyways,how would that feature even be called? I just had an idea, I could add another undecorated panel over that area, that might work. I need a project name for that tho :D

Answer (score 0):

That idea, adding another Window which contains those elements, doesn't seem to be that bad. I already got a gray window roughly at that area. [image: See that gray area?]

Anyways, its not entirely bug-free :D